# custom code in wordpress widget

Tags: email, wordpress, code

I am editing a WordPress site that contains custom HTML in a widget. However, I am unfamiliar with this code as it appears to be code within code and I cannot locate where it originates.

The widget "header fixed right" custom code is shown as:

`<span style="display: inline-block;">[icon_text box_type="normal" icon_pack="linea_icons" icon_type="normal" icon_position="left" icon_size="fa-3x" use_custom_icon_size="no"
text="comfort@acutehvacr.com" title_tag="h5" separator="no" title="843-899-COOL (2665) <br>" image="276" title_color="#00aeac" text_color="#949494"]</span>`

I need to turn the email into a simple sendmail. Any thoughts on where or how I can plug in the correct code for an email link? If I plug in `link=abc.com` the site will show "Read More" with a link to "abc.com"

Answer (score 0):

link=mailto:joecool@abc.com

[wikipedia/mailto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto)

Comment: Yes i do know of "mailto:..." The issue I have here is because this is code within code, if I set in the code "link=mailto:joecool@abc.com" within the [ ... ] the resulting website will display "Read More" as if the code "link" = "Read More"

Answer (score 0):

My apologies. This was an issue with the plug-in "QODE" inside the WP dashboard. I queried their support board and found it to be a limitation of the widget. They supplied a line of js code to fix the issue. In case someone runs into this same issue, this was the support response:

> If we are correct, these are Icon With Text shortcodes. It is not possible to add a link to text directly. The only solution is to do it via custom JS - please add the following code into Qode Options -> General -> Custom JS field and check the header:

```
$j( '.header_fixed_right_area .textwidget > span:first-of-type .q_icon_with_title .icon_text_inner > p' ).wrapInner('<a href="mailto:info@pancabudi.com"></a>');
```